Is it possible to export both results and query when Savings Results As CSV?
Using SSMS 18.9.2, is there is an easy way to include the query code into the results when I Save Results As (CSV)?
I see the option to "Include the Query in the Result Set". And this seems to save the query into the results section into a "Messages" tab. I was hoping there was an easy way to export both the results and messages into csv at once.
I have typically resorted to select all/copying the query, and manually creating another tab and pasting the query within that created tab. I was hoping there was a more efficient way to do this, but perhaps not.

If you are dumping the query at the start of the CSV file, it's not a valid CSV any more; this smells like an XY Problem.
